# Magento form problem in add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a marketplace assign product also i used ajax cart in my site

in below form if more then one seller is there it will be display check the link http://kidsdial.com/peacock-bebe-blocks-set-no-7.html

My problem is if i add a second seller product into the cart it won't add first seller price only added

I think problem is id anyone help me out this

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form1">

    <button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>"  class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>">
    <span>
    <span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span></span></button><div>
    <button class="button buy-now" onclick="location.href ='{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1'">
    <span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button></div>

</form>
```

My .js File

```
if(el.up('form#product_addtocart_form1')){
                    var url =   $('product_addtocart_form1').readAttribute('action');
                    var link = url.replace('checkout','ajaxcart').replace('wishlist/index','ajaxcart/wishlist').replace('https','http');                    
                    el.onclick = function(){
                        if(productAddToCartForm.submit){
                            var emajcForm = productAddToCartForm;
                            if (('undefined' != typeof productAddToCartFormOld) && productAddToCartFormOld)
                                emajcForm   =   productAddToCartFormOld;
                            if(emajcForm.validator && emajcForm.validator.validate()){
                                jQuery('#product_addtocart_form1').ajaxForm(options);
                                $('product_addtocart_form1').setAttribute("action", link);
                                jQuery('#product_addtocart_form1').submit();
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing for the both the forms your id is same **product_addtocart_form1**

Also you have same product id with both the form action which is 219 in URL.

```
http://kidsdial.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2tpZHNkaWFsLmNvbS9wZWFjb2NrLWJlYmUtYmxvY2tzLXNldC1uby03Lmh0bWw,/product/219/form_key/2tkRnqI72XPH84OX/
```

That means both the action URL are same, when you add to cart the product it will just increase the qty by default. If you have multiple products created in your system for different sellers you will need to pass different product ids in action.

Also you might be need to create form id dynamically otherwise it will give you same action every time when you click any add to cart button.

Comment: can you please tel me how to create dynamically and pass it to the form

Comment: I created dynamic id but how to use in jquery for this dynamic id

Comment: <form action="..." method="..." onsubmit="return checkForm(this);"> you can call onsubmit and check in this function.

Comment: No it's not working it redirct to shooping cart page

Comment: can you please send me that script